# what should I do to restart the kubernetes controller panel after renew the certificate

Tags: kubernetes

Today, my kubernetes(`v1.21`) cluster certificate was expired(1 year), after I using this command to renew the certificate:

```
kubeadm certs renew all
```

the logs shows that the kube-apiserver\etcd should be restart:

```
Done renewing certificates. You must restart the kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler and etcd, so that they can use the new certificates.
```

I have tried this way to restart:

```
[root@k8smasterone ~]# systemctl restart kube-apiserver
Failed to restart kube-apiserver.service: Unit not found.
```

what should I do to restart all the component's properly? I also tried to find the kubernetes pods that did not found pods with kubernetes with api server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Failed to restart kube-apiserver.service: Unit not found.

Restart the kubelet on the **master** node, your kube-apiserver runs as static pod. Example: `systemctl restart kubelet`. When you do this on the master node, all core components (kube-*) will be restarted.

Comment: As per https://v1-23.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#manual-certificate-renewal the proper way to restart static pods is to move their yaml's from `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` to a temporary directory. This rather promplty removes them as containers (under docker), and recreates them once the yaml's are moved back. Restarting kubelet on the node, or on control plane nodes does not have such an effect.

Comment: If your control plane crashed and restarts, do you need to manually move the manifests to tmp and move back for your control plane to come up... in the middle of the night? No, when kubelet starts, it should scan the manifest directory (in fact, there are other source as well) and apply the static pod. You should check if your cluster requires you to always "move" manifest even for update. Note the document link is meant to demonstrate kubelet ability to "watch" for file changed, that's not necessary the lifecycle of the *core components*, though. Read the source code for more details.

Comment: For folks that happy to [deep dive](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/116995).

Comment: This is not work.

Answer (score 8):

On 1.23.5 even after restarting `kubelet` through `systemctl restart kubelet` my `kube-controller-manager` still had errors (`kubectl -n kube-system logs kube-controller-manager-kubeadm` - name will vary according to your node name):

```
error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-controller-manager: Unauthorized
```

Only after following [this documentation](https://v1-23.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/) I was able to fix:

```bash
mkdir tmp
mv /etc/kubernetes/manifests/* tmp/
# Wait until pods stop running (in my case, single master, kubectl stopped working)
mv tmp/* /etc/kubernetes/manifests/
```

Before running the commands above some pods worked, but my cluster was highly inconsistent: wrong endpoints for services, deleted pods from daemonsets would not restart, that is how I suspected the controller was not healthy.